# Hangout Call integeration "join call when activity starts"

Tags: android, google-hangouts

I am using Google hangout in am my android application using intent. When Google hangout activity starts you have to press the join button to initiate the video calling. I wanted to join the call automatically when Google hangout activity starts. Skype provides some URI to perform action like direct call to specific person.

So i was wondering may be we may b hangout provides some useful URI but i didn't found any. Anyways can i directly join the call when activity starts so i don't need to press the Join button.

Comment: Your are taking this wrong, Skype provide this functionality by default no this is not in hangout. But if you find any hangout extension for interaction then its good otherwise you cannot jump into that application on your own.

Comment: Than how an extension jump into calling and changes it's behavior.

Comment: You can use any extension for some extra functionality, if hangout provide your required functionality then you can use that.